# DataInputStream hangs on reading

Tags: android, sockets, windows-10-universal, datainputstream

I am trying to create a chat application between Android and a Windows 10 device. 
I have successfully sent text from Android using `DataOutputStream` and read it in Windows 10 using a data reader class.

My problem is Android is not able to recognize the text from Windows. It displays the result of the `datainputstream.available()` function but the application hangs in case I use the `readString()` or the `readbyte()` function.

**Code in Android for receiving:**

```
DataInputStream  dIn = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
if(dIn.available()>0)
{
    int length = dIn.readInt();  // app hangs in here
    byte[] byteReceived = new byte[length];
    dIn.readFully(byteReceived, 0 , length); // sometimes app hangs here 
    String textReceived = new String(byteReceived);
    text.setText(Client Says: "+ textReceived + "\n");//
}
```

**Data sent from Windows through `datawriter`:**

```
DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream))
{
    writer.UnicodeEncoding=windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
    writer.ByteOrder = windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.LittleEndian;
    uint size =writer.MeasureString(message); 
    writer.WriteUint32(size);
    writer.WriteString(message);
    try
    {
        await writer.StoreAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        switch (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult))
        {
            case SocketErrorStatus.HostNotFound:
                // Handle HostNotFound Error
                throw;
            default:
                throw;
        }
    }

    await writer.FlushAsync();
    writer.DetachStream();
}
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Are the windows size write Int at first transaction?

Comment: What is a `DataWriter`, and why aren't you using a `DataOutputStream` to complement your `DataInputStream`, and where are you writing the length word that you are reading, and where is the call to `available()` that you describe?

Comment: @EJP : Datawriter is the writer stream class in windows uwp. i am writing the work to a textbox

Comment: @EvgeniyMishustin : yes i wrote in windows the writeInt before writing my string

Comment: Great, so you've answered 50% of the questions I asked. How about the rest of it? If you wrote the `writeInt()` why doesn't it appear in the code you posted? And why are you wasting your time calling `available()` at all?

Comment: @EJP  hello.sorry for the unclear explanation of my answers. i updated my code in windows side. available() is to check whether i receive something in android

Answer (score 0):

Your `dIn.readFully` expects **bytes** and not `String`. Moreover, it expects the **exact** number of bytes, as `length` variable. You need to create bytes from String on the windows size and send **the length of byte array** as Int in first transaction. Then you need to transfer this byte array unchanged in second transaction. Try it.

Comment: i also tried sending as bytes from windows using writer.writebytes(coneverted_bytes_of_string).. but didnt work